# SQL Server Pivot and Count Function Error

Tags: sql-server, pivot, common-table-expression

I am using a Common Table Expression and a PIVOT function to get the count of products sold in the past 5 years but I am getting an error. Why am I getting the error below?

```
USE ADVENTUREWOKS2012;

WITH SALESDATA AS
(
    SELECT
        Product.PRODUCTID,
        Product.Name,
        YEAR(OrderDate) AS [YEAR SOLD]
    FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail
    JOIN Production.Product
       ON Product.ProductID = PurchaseOrderDetail.ProductID
    JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader
       ON PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderID = PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderID
    GROUP BY Product.PRODUCTID,Product.Name,YEAR(OrderDate)
)
SELECT Name,
   [2005],
   [2006],
   [2007],
   [2008],
   [2009],
   PRODUCTID
FROM SALESDATA
PIVOT (COUNT(PRODUCTID) FOR [YEAR SOLD] IN ([2005], [2006], [2007], [2008], [2009])) AS P;
```

Error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
>       Invalid column name 'PRODUCTID'.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `ProductId` column in the PIVOT -- `count(productId)` so you can't reference the column in the final select list.  If you want to reference it then alter your query to which includes the column twice so you can keep it in the final select:

```
WITH SALESDATA AS
(
    SELECT
        pivProd = Product.PRODUCTID,
        Product.PRODUCTID,
        Product.Name,
        YEAR(OrderDate) AS [YEAR SOLD]
    FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail
    JOIN Production.Product
       ON Product.ProductID = PurchaseOrderDetail.ProductID
    JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader
       ON PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderID = PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderID
    GROUP BY Product.PRODUCTID,Product.Name,YEAR(OrderDate)
)
SELECT Name,
   [2005],
   [2006],
   [2007],
   [2008],
   [2009],
   PRODUCTID
FROM SALESDATA
PIVOT 
(
  COUNT(pivProd) FOR [YEAR SOLD] IN ([2005], [2006], [2007], [2008], [2009])
) AS P;
```

Or just remove it from the final select:

```
WITH SALESDATA AS
(
    SELECT
        Product.PRODUCTID,
        Product.Name,
        YEAR(OrderDate) AS [YEAR SOLD]
    FROM Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail
    JOIN Production.Product
       ON Product.ProductID = PurchaseOrderDetail.ProductID
    JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader
       ON PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderID = PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderID
    GROUP BY Product.PRODUCTID,Product.Name,YEAR(OrderDate)
)
SELECT Name,
   [2005],
   [2006],
   [2007],
   [2008],
   [2009]
FROM SALESDATA
PIVOT 
(
  COUNT(PRODUCTID) FOR [YEAR SOLD] IN ([2005], [2006], [2007], [2008], [2009])
) AS P;
```